# Correct use of Mathlink's MLGetRealList

Tags: equation-solving, mathlink-or-wstp

I am attempting to use Mathlink from C. I have managed to return single values from mathlink to my c program, but I am having trouble with lists.

Consider the Mathematica operation:

```
NSolve[{x^2 + 4 x + y == 0, y == x + 2}, {x, y}]
```

This gives us:

```
{{x -> -0.438447, y -> 1.56155}, {x -> -4.56155, y -> -2.56155}}
```

Say I wanted to return to my C program a list containing only the second solution i.e. I want {-4.56155,-2.56155}}.

I could do this

```
 List[NSolve[{x^2 + 4 x + y == 0, y == x + 2}, {x, y}][[2]][[1]][[2]], 
 NSolve[{x^2 + 4 x + y == 0, y == x + 2}, {x, y}][[2]][[2]][[2]]]
```

In mathematica, this gives me:

```
{-4.56155, -2.56155}
```

All very well, but I worried mathematica is doing Nsolve twice.

When I try to replicate this through C like this:

```
MLPutFunction(link, "EvaluatePacket", 1);
    MLPutFunction(link, "ToExpression", 1);
    MLPutString(link, (const char *)"List[NSolve[{x^2 + 4 x + y == 0, y == x + 2}, {x, y}][[2]][[2]][[2]], NSolve[{x^2 + 4 x + y == 0, y == x + 2}, {x, y}][[2]][[1]][[2]]]");
    MLEndPacket(link);

    while (MLNextPacket(link) != RETURNPKT)
    {
         MLNewPacket(link);
    }

    double *list;
    long length;

    MLGetRealList(link, &list, &length);

    std::cout<<list[0]<<std::cout;

    MLDisownRealList(link, list, length);
```

EDIT: The program sort of completes, but I thin kit is crashing at the end.

Now when I print out list[0] and list[1] I get the right answer followed by a hex value.

E.g.:

```
-4.561550x7fff7986fb68
```

1) How can I return a list of numbers in an elegant fashion through Mathlink?
2) Why is it crashing?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

this problem can be fixed by changing

```
std::cout<<list[0]<<std::cout;
```

to

```
std::cout<<list[0]<<std::endl;
```